# Laravel link_to attributes aren't working for me..?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the following...

```
$params = array('amount' => $transaction_details['AMT']);
echo link_to('/transaction/'.$transaction_details['TRANSACTIONID'].'/refund', 'Refund', $params);
```

I'm getting my link that goes to the correct URL, but it's not adding URL parameters to it at all, which is what I thought the 3rd attribute would do where I'm passing in the $params array.  I can verify that $transaction_details['AMT'] does have a value.

Any info on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the 3rd parameter. The attributes refer to the actual HTML element. For example:

```
$params = array('class' => 'btn');
echo link_to('/link', 'I am a link', $params);
```

Would result in:

```
<a href="/link" class="btn">I am a link</a>
```

Comment: Doh!  That's why it's called $attributes and not $params.  :)

Answer (score 0):

@geevCookie is correct. To add the parameters to your URL you can use the URL helper.

```
echo link_to(url('/transaction/'.$transaction_details['TRANSACTIONID'].'/refund', $params), 'Refund');
```

Comment: Ok, so this works to create a link like this (http://paypal-glass.angelleye.com/transaction/9NB29866W2763682E/refund/100.00) where 100.00 is the amount I'm passing, but then how do  I pull that value back out from within my view?  And what if I pass more than 1 value?  How do I pick them out specifically?  Do I have to create specific routes for every possible collection of data I might send?  Seems like I'm definitely missing something here..??

Comment: Would it be better to just flash the data I need on the next view?